# Make PowerShell windows disappear

Tags: powershell

I made a PowerShell backupscript. I also made a GUI for it.
Now I would like that the PowerShell Windows behind the GUI disappears during the script.

Is there a simple command for it or how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Start PowerShell with `-windowsstyle` hidden parameter i.e:

```
powershell.exe -noprofile -windowstyle hidden -executionpolicy bypass -NonInteractive -file .\script.ps1
```